# Implementing interfaces with parentheses notation

Tags: go

I spent some times to look for an explanation about a piece of code I've seen somewhere.
The code is about

```
type Freder interface {
    Manger()
}

type Fred struct {
    poids int
}

func (f Fred) Manger() { fmt.Println("Hello, 世界") }

func main() {
    f := Fred{68}
    a := Freder(f)
```

Because `Fred` is satisfying the `Freder` interface, it's using the instantiated struct explicitly in the interface statement.
It's quite disturbing for me because I thought we have to use the literal form with curly brackets when instantiating

```
    t := reflect.TypeOf(a)
    fmt.Println(t) // <-- main.Fred
    fmt.Println(a) // {68}
```

My question is how is called that kind of statement ? Where could I read some documentation about it ?

Comment: `Freder(f) ` => this is simply a type conversion, so type of `a` will be `Freder`. If you do `a := f`, then type of `a` will be `Fred`.